# Tracking badge progress

Tags: discussion, badges

I really enjoy working towards badges.

How can I track my progress towards badges? For example, the Gold copy editor? Or perhaps (dare I ask), the Legendary badge (I think I'm 1/150th of the way towards this one)?

Comment: See also these meta.SO questions (and answers there): [Badge progress reports](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports) and
[Where can I find badge progress for Copy Editor and Electorate on the new review page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140111/where-can-i-find-badge-progress-for-copy-editor-and-electorate-on-the-new-review).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Specific to the badges you mention, here are some ways of establishing them:

---

[image: Copy editor badge]

Under any of the statistics pages associated with reviews (for example, the [Review Close Votes page](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats)), hover over the review progress bar to open up a fly-out that contains the relevant information:

[image]

As can be seen, this fly-out also contains other badge progress information specific to the [Reviewer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/reviewer), [Civic Duty](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) and [Electorate](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate).

---

[image: Legendary badge]

Visit the [reputation calculator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation) and scroll to the bottom. It displays the following information:

```
days represented XXX
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on XXX days
earned at least 200 reputation on XXX days
earned XXX reputation from suggested edits
```

where the (silver) [epic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/42/epic) and (gold) [legendary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/43/legendary) badges are measurable via the statement `earned at least 200 reputation on XXX days`.

---

However, a reasonable way (barring a time lag of a couple of months, sadly enough) of establishing your road to badge-stardom is via the [TeX StackExchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/queries). For example:

- [What is the most recent post the data explorer has?](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/8800/what-is-the-most-recent-post-the-data-explorer-has)
- [How many edits until Copy Editor (proper)?](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/56748/how-many-edits-until-copy-editor-proper)
- [Epic/Legendary Badges](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/32763/epic-legendary-badges)
- [On what days did I hit the reputation cap?](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/3834/on-what-days-did-i-hit-the-reputation-cap)
- [How long until I get the pundit badge?](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/10098/how-long-until-i-get-the-pundit-badge)
- [Generalist Progression #updated](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/35591/generalist-progression-updated)
- [Users statistics (individual user)](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/13294/users-statistics-individual-user)
- [What is my Archaeologist badge progress?](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/69607/what-is-my-archaeologist-badge-progress)

In particular, scroll through and check out the [list of favoured queries](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/queries?order_by=favorite).

Comment: "How many edits until Copy Editor (proper)" is not proper. I have 79 edits just now, the script says I have 20 of them, which is a nonsense.

Comment: @tohecz That *might* be the time lag that Werner mentions.

Comment: @AndrewStacey That's a _long_ lag.

Comment: @tohecz: I tracked the time lag to about 3 months. However, [What is the most recent post the data explorer has?](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/8800/what-is-the-most-recent-post-the-data-explorer-has) suggests it's more like 2 months. The entire SE network data is available for [download via torrent](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump); I'm thinking they're using a similar setup for the SE Data Explorer, where a separate dump of data (not live) is used for queries. As such, it could be up to 3 months behind, since that's the reported release schedule.

Comment: @tohecz The no. of edits shown on the "Users" page is (for whatever reason) *not* the one that's relevant for the "Copy Editor" badge. Right now, the page reports 13 users with at least 500 edits, but there are only 10 users who earned the badge.

Comment: @lockstep: Based on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116380/168244), there are a number of things that might not count towards the Copy Editor badge: (1) edits to your own posts, (2) tag only edits, (3) *maybe* repeated edits to the same post.

Comment: [Is the number of edits on the users page the one relevant for the edit badges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108816) confirms @lockstep's last comment.

Comment: @doncherry: Thanks - I've included your reference as a reference...

Answer (score 10):

There's a Stack App called [StinkingBadges](https://stackapps.com/q/2982/10487), with which you can track you progress for Legendary and Generalist, and also which posts of yours are approaching a nice/good/great badge.

[image]